# To create tr & td dynamically and append to table. Onclick pass the json selected object

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

To append rows to existing table. On each onclick had to pass the selected object.

```
function populateResult(data, resultElementId){
              $.each(data, function(i,row){

                      $tr = $('<tr><td>'+ row.name+'</td></tr>' ).appendTo(resultElementId);

                      $tr.on("click", myfunction(row));

              });
}



function myfunction(shipObj){
     console.log("data :"+JSON.stringify(shipObj));
}
```

myfunction this method is not invoking on onclick.

Note: I am using jquery 1.7

Comment: Don't forget to `</tr>`

Comment: Thanks added. But still its not working on Onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value of `row` as json object i.e :`{'datas': row}` inside click event handler and then access this using *event* object  .i.e : `e.data.datas` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function populateResult(data, resultElementId) {
  $.each(data, function(i, row) {
    $trs = $(`<tr><td> ${row.name} </td></tr>`).appendTo(resultElementId);
    //on click pass that row as well
    $trs.on('click', {
      'datas': row
    }, myfunction);
  })

}
 function myfunction(e) {
 //use event object to access data
    console.log('Data :  ' + JSON.stringify(e.data.datas));
  }



populateResult([{
  "name": "s1",
}, {
  "name": "s2"
}], "#myTableBody")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="myTableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to achieve what you need. Here's two:

### Assign the click handler to a delegator parent

```js
$("#table tbody").on("click", "tr", function() {
  // get the tbody TR index and that's its position in the data array
  const idx = $(this).index();
  const row = data[idx];
  myfunction(row);
});
```

or

### Create TRs with a click handler already assigned

```js
function populateResult(data, resultElementId) {
  $.each(data, (i, row) => $("<tr>", {
    html: `<td>${row.name}</td>`,
    appendTo: resultElementId,
    click() {
      myfunction(row)
    }
  }));
}
```

Demo of the last example:

```js
function populateResult(data, resultElementId) {
  $.each(data, (i, row) => $("<tr>", {
    html: `<td>${row.name}</td>`,
    appendTo: resultElementId,
    click() {
      myfunction(row)
    }
  }));
}

function myfunction(shipObj) {
  console.log("data :" + JSON.stringify(shipObj));
}

const data = [{name:"Lorem"}, {name: "Ipsum"}];
populateResult(data, "#myTableBody");
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="myTableBody"></tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but im using jquery 1.7